# HTML/CSS to make an image container the same size as those next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a row of images and product descriptions. It looks like this:
[image]

The image on the right obviously has a smaller height than the two preceding it. I'd like to make it look more like this:

[image]

But I'm at a bit of a loss as to how. Here are the caveats:

1. I don't know the dimensions of the images in advance, these are being called in via AJAX from my database
2. I don't want a javascript solution, I'd much much prefer a CSS-based solution.
3. I'm using `Bootstrap`, if that has any bearing here.
4. This is built using AngularJS' `ng-repeat` where one `repeat` equals one 'product', as in the images above. Thus creating a `<tr>` which contains the row of images and simply giving them `vertical-align="middle"` won't work here.

Because of the last factor, I'm assuming it won't be possible to do this without javascript. Here's a JSFiddle which has the code inside:

http://jsfiddle.net/CTVZR/5/

Any ideas/solutions? I'd gladly display them in a table if it were possible but I can't think of a way how.

Comment: css min-height attribute might be useful here (doesn't work in older versions of IE)

Comment: Hi there, I edited my answer; check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` and `table-cell` [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/CTVZR/12/)

```
.row {
    display: table;
}
.col-xs-4
{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: This is close, but the `vertical-align:bottom` doesn't display how I asked in the question. The images should be the same height while the text at the bottom can be any height (as there will be varying amounts of words displayed depending on the product).

Comment: @Jascination I can't think of a possible way of doing this with your current HTML structure without using JS.

Answer (score 1):

**html solution:** not the best for most caes but simple
you can set in the img tag the height or the width (or both) so they will all be the same
ex:

all the images will be resized to heigth="100px" proportionally
(if you set width and height then you will loos the auto proportion)

**CSS solution -background**
instead of an img tag use a div and set its background to be the image you want.
you can set the position as center or in percent or px. and you can set scaling.

ex:
background: url('the url') no-repeat center;
look at the link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

CSS 3 solution
try to play with the image min-height and min-width (and maybe max)

Answer (score 0):

With JS, you need to loop and check for the highest and apply this value to the others

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.searchImgContainer').each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $('.searchImgContainer').css('height',maxHeight);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toniweb/CTVZR/14/

-EDIT, the align bottom image-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.searchImgContainer').each(function(){
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if(currentHeight > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = currentHeight;
        }
    });
    $('.searchImgContainer').each(function(){
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if(currentHeight < maxHeight){
              margin = maxHeight - currentHeight; $(this).find('img').css('marginTop',margin);
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toniweb/CTVZR/16/

-EDIT, Itay is making me work! ^^ -

```
function fixImages(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.searchImgContainer').each(function(){
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if(currentHeight > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = currentHeight;
        }
    });
    $('.searchImgContainer').each(function(){
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if(currentHeight < maxHeight){
              margin = maxHeight - currentHeight; $(this).find('img').css('marginTop',margin);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(fixImages);
$(window).resize(fixImages);
```

Comment: Don't forget to make it stick to bottom.

Comment: Also attach the resize event because it's flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I would think of would be to give `height` a certain value and `position:relative` and to images inside them give `position:absolute`, `bottom:0` and `max-height` the same as height of the container. Give it a try.